# how to reload whole tableview controller from other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my project there is one slide menu and that menu is **table view controller**.and it **contain 13** element now.in this menu one row contain sign in option now once user sign in and come again to open that menu i want **11 element** in that table view controller.I am using plist to fetch data and when user once signing in i am taking data from another **plist** that contain 11 element.
Now my question is after signing in i am not able to reload **table view controller cell** it is showing 13 element and once i close the app and again open the app table get refresh.i tried every possible solutions for reloading that element but its not working.Even i had tried from appdelegate didfinishlaunchingwithoption method by passing notification center message but it cant works.
Please help if anybody have idea or solution.

Comment: Use protocol/delegate to reload the table from the class through which you want to reload the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you can use [Local-notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) to reload the tableview controller  from other class or  view-controller

you need to set one observer in uitableviewcontroller .m file  and trigger it  from  other  class where you want it to reload  the tableview

you can achieve this by doing this add this trigger to the other class from where you want  to  reload the table

```
 NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:@“reloadTable" object:self userInfo:nil];
```

after that setup this observer in tableviewcontroller class and create the receiver method

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable:) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
```

create this receiver method in tableviewcontroller class

```
-(void) reloadTable: (NSNotification* )note{
 NSLog(@"Inside : NSNotification");
[self.tableview  reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try reloading the table inside viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method in the Tableviewcontroller.m so that when the menu appears on screen each time...it gets refreshed